# How to access data from json through javaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, database, data-visualization

I'm trying to make a data visualization with JS, getting the values from a dynamic json file, but I can't get to visualize my data past the console.

The idea is to be able to use those 4 values (outputValue0, outputValue1, outputValue2, outputValue3)to modify a shape and the colors of itself. How should I be calling my variables to access to them in javaScript?

This is my code:

```
var lines = "waiting for data"; 
var val0 = 0; // I get a 0, of course, but I need the actual value
var val0 = []; //I get nothing with this

function setup() {
createCanvas(400,400);
loadJSON('http://www.----------.com/data_to_json.php', gotData);
}

Object.size = function(obj){
var size = 0, key;
for(key in obj){
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
}
return size;
}

function gotData(data) {

var size = Object.size(data) - 1;
console.log(size);
console.log(data[size]['timeStamp']);
console.log(data[size]['outputValue0'] + " " + data[size]['outputValue1'] + " " + data[size]['outputValue2']+ " " + data[size]['outputValue3']);
 lines = size;
 var val0 = data[size]['outputValue0'];

 }

 function draw(){
 background(158, 152, 207);
 textAlign(LEFT);
 fill(0);
 text('Emotional analysis', 10, height - 370);
 text(lines + ' emotions stored',10,height -20);
 text(val0,10,height -60)

 }
```

I have few errors on my console, but I think it's not related:

> InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable
>   El uso del sensor de orientación está obsoleto. (the use of the sensor is obsolete)
>   p5.js:9298:6
>   El uso del sensor de moviento está obsoleto. (the use of the sensor is obsolete)
>   p5.js:9298:6
>   240
>   sketch.js:20:3
>   2019-02-08 22:03:09
>   sketch.js:21:3
>   20 20 19 20
>   sketch.js:22:3

​
The json file looks like this:

```
[{"timeStamp":"2019-02-08 13:38:53","outputValue0":"18","outputValue1":"18","outputValue2":"18","outputValue3":"18"},
{"timeStamp":"2019-02-08 13:39:03","outputValue0":"18","outputValue1":"18","outputValue2":"19","outputValue3":"18"},
{"timeStamp":"2019-02-08 13:39:13","outputValue0":"18","outputValue1":"18","outputValue2":"19","outputValue3":"18"},
{"timeStamp":"2019-02-08 13:39:23","outputValue0":"18","outputValue1":"19","outputValue2":"19","outputValue3":"19"},
{"timeStamp":"2019-02-08 13:39:33","outputValue0":"18","outputValue1":"19","outputValue2":"20","outputValue3":"19"}]
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code (errors, unexpected results, etc.)? In particular, what is displayed by those `console.log` statements inside `gotData`?

Comment: the way you're accessing them now in the console looks to be ok...unless you can tell us about an error? If you want to use them to do something else, then from the gotData function you need to pass them to whatever function you use to modify your shapes. It's unclear what/where that function is, or what arguments it accepts. But surely you know how to call a function?

Comment: Bear in mind that once you have parsed a JSON string successfully into a JS variable, it becomes like any other object or array...you can access the properties in the normal way, run loops to go through the data items, etc. It's no different.

Comment: @p.s.w.g I've edited my post adding my console errors now, thanks!

Comment: Thanks. The results of your `console.log()` statements inside the gotData() function would be the most relevant thing for us to see, I think.

Comment: Perhaps `loadJSON` call is failing due to a network error, or perhaps the response data isn't being parsed correctly. Surely there's some way to handle that error, but I'd have to see how `loadJSON` is defined (it's not a standard function or part of any library I recognize). Also, where and how is `setup` called? Honestly, there's a lot of basic debugging information missing; this question could really use a [**MCVE**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You should be careful when extending built-in objects like `Object`, especially without checking if the function already exists. You could just as easily just make a global `size` function that does the same thing (or just use `Object.keys(obj).length`).

Comment: @ADyson Thanks! I've added some modifications so you can understand better where I'm struggling

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks for the reply! I'm sorry, I'm still a begginer so I'm really lost with your reply, please check my edit and maybe you can understand better what I'm missing

Comment: Not horribly important, and nothing to do with your question, just an observation/caution about using `Object.size = function` instead of just `var size = function`. Somewhere down the road, if JavaScript adds a `size` function to `Object`, your code would override that function.

Comment: @p.s.w.g I don't understand your reply... can you please check my update so maybe you understand what I'm trying to do? thanks!

Comment: rather than using global variables, pass your variables around from one function to another. `val0` will not have any value, because you never assign one to it. Even within gotData, when you write `var val0` this creates a new variable called `val0` which only exists within the function. If you drop the `var` it will change the global `val0` instead. But it's a bad design pattern really. Maybe you should read about [variable scope](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-variables-scope-hoisting-in-javascript) to understand this a bit better

Comment: Meanwhile, I see you then try to use `val0` within the draw() function. I assume this is the function which is supposed to change your shape? You never did clarify that. In the code you've shown, you never actually call the "draw()" function anywhere. If you want to use the values taken from the JSON, you'd have to call it from within the `gotData` function - otherwise those values won't have been set yet.

Comment: Now, it would be better for encapsulation perhaps if draw accepted some parameters e.g. `function draw(val0, val1, val2, val3) {`. Then in the gotData function you could write `draw(data[size]['outputValue0'], data[size]['outputValue1'], data[size]['outputValue2'], data[size]['outputValue3']);` to pass the values to it, and alter your shape. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: I simply mean that's it's really hard to tell what's going on because this is still only a partial code sample. We can offer tips and pointers, but ultimately we're just guessing, too. There could be any number of issues, and to help us figure out how to best help you, we would need to see a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @ADyson Thanks a lot! I'ts working as you suggested :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be attempting to populate some global variables. But you've made mistakes with scope, and also this is generally considered a flawed design pattern. Also at the moment you don't seem to have anywhere where you actually call the `draw()` function.

It would be better for encapsulation perhaps if `draw()` accepted some parameters e.g.

```
function draw(val0, val1, val2, val3) {
```

Then in the gotData function you could write

```
draw(data[size]['outputValue0'], data[size]['outputValue1'], data[size]['outputValue2'], data[size]['outputValue3']);
```

to pass the values to it, and alter your shape.